# Create unique props variable for each thread in Jmeter

Tags: multithreading, properties, jmeter

I want to create properties variable for each Thread and this is unique and i can use it in another input. So does anyone can suggest me the way to do it? Is __threadNUm is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In order to set the property you can use [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combination like:

   ```
   ${__setProperty(PROPERTY_PREFIX_${__threadNum},PROPERTY_VALUE,)}
   ```

   Replace `PROPERTY_PREFIX` and `PROPERTY_VALUE` with your own values
2. To read the property value per thread you can use [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combination like:

   ```
   ${__P(PROPERTY_PREFIX_${__threadNum},)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

---

Another solution is using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) which is handy for sharing values across different threads (even if they are in different thread groups). The exact instructions will differ depending on what you're trying to achieve, you can see [SynchronizationExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx) test plan for reference.

You can install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]